# Is Chi's Sweet Home 3D a sequel or a reboot?

Tags: chis-sweet-home

Is "Chi's Sweet Home 3D" an anime sequel of "Chi's New Address" or is it just a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Chi's Sweet home is the Prequel to Chi's New address.

Chi's sweet home aired from Mar 31, 2008 till Sep 25, 2008.

Around the same time the following year Chi's new address aired from Mar 30, 2009 till Sep 24, 2009

Source: [Chis Sweet Home](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3841/Chis_Sweet_Home) &  [Chis Sweet Home Atarashii Ouchi](https://myanimelist.net/anime/6024/Chis_Sweet_Home__Atarashii_Ouchi).

Answer (score 0):

*Chi's Sweet Home* started as a (wonderful and highly recommended by me) manga by Konami Kanata. It ran from 2004 to 2015, though nobody seemed to age in those 11 years. :3

It was adapted into an anime series (of 2.5 minute episodes) called *Chi's Sweet Home* in 2008. This basically adapts the first book of the manga.

As a follow-up, *Chi's New Address* (2009) further adapts Kanata's manga, but takes some serious deviations when it outpaced the source. It tries to bring some of that together by the end of the series. For some reason, this "season" is on Crunchyroll, but the previous one is not; however, both are available to buy on Region 1 DVD.

Additionally, a 13-minute special adapts Chi's first meeting with Cocchi ("Chi Meets Cocchi", 2010), another kitten character who hadn't otherwise appeared in the animated version. As far as I can tell, this hasn't receive a North American release.

The 2016 series is itself a reboot of the original series, or, more appropriately, a re-adaptation of the manga.